# Avegaring a harmonic function over solid angle

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

It is well-known fact that if you average a harmonic function over the area of a sphere,  you get the value of the harmonic function evaluated at the sphere's center.
(Let's restrict the dimension to 3.)

But as we can understand this averaging is done over solid angle, I was motivated to generalize it to some point other than the center of the sphere.

Does the average over solid angle with respect to the pont other than the center of the sphere have any meaning?

(sorry for lack of any rigorous equations. It's hard to type TEX codes on mobile device, so let me edit it later...)

Comment: I read this as asking: Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct points of $\mathbf{R}^3$, let $B$ be a ball centered at $p$ that contains $q$, and let $f$ be a harmonic function on $B$. If $B'$ is a ball centered at $q$ and contained in $B$, does the integral of $f$ over $B'$ (or its boundary sphere) have an interpretation, preferably in terms of $f$ and $p$?

If this interpretation is right: Since $f$ is harmonic in $B'$, the average of $f$ over $B'$ (or over its boundary) is $f(q)$; there is no way to express this in terms of $f$ and $p$.

But this is trivial, so perhaps something else was meant?

Comment: Almost right interpretation but not exactly what I wanted to ask : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575674/where-nabla2v-0-evaluate-int-s-v-d-omega-4-pi I asked new question with equation, so please check it out and I will thank you if you can provide some advice.