# where $\nabla^2V = 0$ , evaluate $\int_S V d\Omega /4\pi$

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, harmonic-functions

Where $\nabla^2 V = 0$ in 3 dimensional Euclidean space, it is a well-known fact that $${\int_S V(\vec{r'})  d\Omega'\over 4\pi}=V(\vec{a})$$
where $\vec{a}$ is the center of a sphere $S$ of radius $R$ , $d\Omega'$ is infinitesimal solid angle of surface area of $S$ from the point $\vec{a}$, and the integration is done of the surface of $S$.

But I want to know what happens if the integration is done with respect to some point other than $\vec{a}$ where the sphere $S$ is unchanged. Let us call such point $\vec{r}$. My expectation is that it would turn out to be some function similar to $V(\vec{r})$. But I cannot make any progress in my calcaulation. I am also curious about the dependence of the integration on whether $\vec{r}$ is in $S$ or not. Thnak you!

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Are you asking what will happen to the integral if one replace the area element $d\Omega'$ on $S$ by the 'infinitesimal' solid angle w.r.t. to another point $\vec{r}$???

Comment: $d\Omega'$ itself is already 'infinitesimal' solid angle w.r.t. the center of the sphere. I'm asking what will happen to the integral if we change the reference point from the center of the sphere to another point $\vec{r}$.

Comment: To amplify on achille hui's comment: The integral on the left depends on $\vec{a}$ only because the sphere $S$ is centered at $\vec{a}$; the _integrand_ does not depend on $\vec{a}$. If you want to "change $\vec{r}$ but integrate $f$ over $S$", you must specify an integrand (or a surface of integration) that depends on $\vec{r}$.

Comment: Actually, integrand changes because the way to evaluate $d\Omega'$ changes depending on the reference point ($\vec{r}$ or$ \vec{a}$)

Comment: $d\Omega'$=$dA'/R^2$=$dA'/\eta ^2$, where $\eta$ is the distance between $\vec{r'}$ and $\vec{r}$

Comment: Ah: What you're denoting $d\Omega'$ I (mis-)understood (based on your comment to achille hui) to be what you're calling $dA'$.

Comment: As a test case, have you calculated what happens if $V=z$ and $\vec{r}=(0,0,z_0)$, with $-1<z_0<1$? The integral is elementary (in spherical coordinates it's a rational function of sine) and looks tractable, albeit a little messy.